# jQuery - Using .each() inside of a function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set up a function that calculates the total when two `inputs` are changed within an `.item`. I want this to happen for the `inputs` on each `.item` only, but currently the way I have set up my `calculateTotal()` function does not run for each `.item` on `keyup`

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".qty").val();
    var price = item.find(".cost").val();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    $(".totalprice").text(total);
  });
}
calculateTotal();
$(".input--item").keyup(function() {
  calculateTotal();
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="12" maxlength="3" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="55" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="totalprice"></span><br>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="40" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="79" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="totalprice"></span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".totalprice", this)` <= you need to find the totalprice for each of the items.  or `item.find('.totalprice')` since you already have a jQuery object for the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `item.find(".totalprice").text(total)`

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".qty").val();
    var price = item.find(".cost").val();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    item.find(".totalprice").text(total)
    
  });
}
calculateTotal();
$(document).keyup('.input--item',function() {
  calculateTotal();
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="12" maxlength="3" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="55" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
  </div>
 <span class="totalprice"></span><br>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="40" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="79" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="totalprice"></span><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are changing text of all the divs, instead you have to change the div for the current item, do it like this

```js
function calculateTotal() {
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);
    var qty = item.find(".qty").val();
    var price = item.find(".cost").val();
    var total = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    $(this).find(".totalprice").text(total);
  });
}

calculateTotal();
$(".input--item").on("input",function() {
  calculateTotal();
});
```

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrap {
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="12" maxlength="3" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="55" maxlength="4" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="totalprice"></span><br>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    Cost:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item qty" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="40" />
    </div>
    Price:
    <div class="edit">
      <input class="input--item cost" type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" value="79" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="totalprice"></span><br>
</div>
```